# Form based login on HTTPS fails with browser error that it couldn't connect the server

Tags: security, tomcat, servlets, authentication, web.xml

I'm trying to implement a simple form-based login for my web application deployed with Tomcat. loginPage.html has `j_username` and `j_password` as fields, and the form method is `j_security_check`, as specified. /Actions is a directory containing all of my html and jsp files, as well as the css and js files, and all of the servlet mappings are of the form /Actions/servletName.do. The only pages not in actions are index.html and loginPage and loginError.

Right now, the home page is index.html. There is a hyperlink to Actions/home.html in it. What I want is for that hyperlink to redirect to loginPage.html first, and then when the user logs in it will go to home.html. My understanding is that, since home.html is a constrained resource, this should happen automatically. However, instead, I am not redirected to a login page, and the browser displays an error saying it couldn't connect to the page; the URL at the top is either https://localhost:8443/myProject/Actions/home.html and https://localhost:8443/myProject/index.html.

I have looked at several tutorials but nowhere do they specify a complete example, including file locations. Help would be greatly appreciated. Oh yes, and if anyone's wondering, I did update the tomcat-users.xml file accordingly.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-role><role-name>Admin</role-name></security-role>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/loginPage.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AllResources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Actions/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? What's the *exact* error message? Does http:// work for `index.html`? This sounds much like that SSL isn't configured on your container at all.

Comment: I used Chrome which said "Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured." But I thought Tomcat was configured for SSL. Attempting to go directly to /Actions/home.html produces the exact same error.

Comment: When I enter http://localhost:8080/myServlet/ or http://localhost:8080/myServlet/index.html, it goes to the right page but the url at the top is shown without the http://

Comment: Should I switch back to the BASIC authorization method? I thought tomcat was configured for SSL because the book Head First Servlets & JSP I am using doesn't say otherwise and it has an example of this, but unfortunately not a full one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [configure Tomcat to use SSL](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) first whenever you'd like to use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure). Otherwise you have to remove the `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` entry and fix all links in your HTML/JSP files to point to `http://` instead of `https://`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if the computer it will be deployed upon is configured for SSL. Also, I am under the impression that it's not secure to use form-based login without the Confidential guarantee. So should I switch back to basic?

Comment: Containers are usually not by default configured for SSL. It requires an admin-provided certificate keystore file. See also the HOWTO link in my answer. HTTP basic authentication is not more secure than form based authentication. The difference is just that authentication takes place by a bare browser-builtin popup dialogue instead of a HTML form where you've all the control over the look'n'feel. It's really SSL which makes difference in security. All data is then transferred encrypted over network.

Comment: Isn't basic encrypted with base64, while form is not encrypted at all if not given a transport guarantee?

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption. It's just an encoding to ensure that proper characters are been sent (which is reversible without need for a key). The HTTP basic authentication information is passed as a request header instead of in the POST request body as with a HTML form. Request headers have limited support for allowed characters.

Comment: Looks like I'll just go with the form without the transport guarantee. Is this super easy to crack, though?

Comment: It's indeed sensitive to main-in-the-middle attacks. E.g. a sniffer/logger in a network router/proxy/gateway. Not exactly super easy, but definitely something to watch out for. You definitely don't want to skip HTTPS whenever the restricted data concerns extremely sensitive information like banking account information.

Comment: Well, thanks for all your help. I believe one will need to be on a secure network anyway to access the index.html, so hopefully that won't happen, but while the information isn't exactly ultra sensitive it's not unsensitive, so perhaps it will be configured for SSL anyway. (If I said something that sounds glaringly strange, please ignore it, I'm not very experienced). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Discuss about it with your client and serveradmin.